# Why we cannot calculate an ROC curve in cost sensitive learning?

Tags: roc, auc, imbalanced-data, cohen-kappa

In the Applied Predictive Modeling book, cost sensitivity learning approach, the author(s) write:

> One consequence of this approach is that class probabilities cannot be
> generated for the model, at least in the available implementation.
> Therefore we cannot calculate an ROC curve and must use a different
> performance metric. Instead we will now use the Kappa statistic,
> sensitivity, and specificity to evaluate the impact of weighted
> classes.

Can you explain to me why not ROC/AUC but Kappa Statistic, sensitivity and specificity  instead? I think sensitivity or specificity is also ROC or AUC?

Link for the book: https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/bafykbzacedepga3g6t7b6rq6irwhy5gzpc47bamquhygup4eqggidvkjcztqs?filename=Max%20Kuhn%2C%20Kjell%20Johnson%20-%20Applied%20Predictive%20Modeling-Springer%20%282013%29.pdf

Comment: Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com or maybe datascience.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh, so I guess that stackoverflow is mainly for coding questions?

Comment: Yes, that's right.